# can't find location via Corelocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I use corelocation to detect Latitude and longitude to use in URL but log has print in 0.00000 in both

this  is my code

mapViewcontroller.m

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface mapsViewController () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *mapsweb;
@property(weak,nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationmanager;
@end

@implementation mapsViewController

-(NSString *)getlat{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_locationmanager.location.coordinate.latitude];
}
-(NSString *)getlon{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_locationmanager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    _locationmanager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
    _locationmanager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    _locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
    [_locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSString *t1 = @"http://mymaps.com/clat/";
    NSString *la = [self getlat];
    NSString *t2 = @"/clng/";
    NSString *lo = [self getlon];

    NSLog(@"latitude is %@",[self getlat]);
    NSLog(@"Longitude is %@",[self getlon]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't use requestWhenInUseAuthorization or requestAlwaysAuthorization

also check with below delegates-

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I use Objective-C don't swift

Answer (score 1):

Have you added NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in Info.plist? If not then add this property and make its type as String and value = requestWhenInUseAuthorization